# Unity 2d stop moving while attacking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I creating a 2d platformer, so the problem is, I want the player to stop moving while attacking I know this is a simple problem I can't figure it out, I try boolean but it's not working or I just really don't know how to use it
Here's the code:

```
bool canMove=true;
bool canAttack;

void Update()
{
    float pos = Input. GetAxis("Horizontal");

    if(canMove && Vector2 != 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(pos*walkspeed, 0);
        canAttack =false;
    }
    else
    {
        canAttack = true;
    } 

    if(canAttack)
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
        {
            Attack();
    rb.velocity = Vector2. zero;
            canMove = false;
        } 
        else
        {
            canMove = true;
        } 
    }
}
```

It seems I can't input the entire code

Comment: I fixed your indentations and some typos like `can Attack` and `can Move` .... but what is `Vector2 != 0` supposed to do?

Comment: Hmmm I think it's making sure that the player is not moving

Comment: Well I think this wouldn't even compile ;) Do you maybe mean `pos != 0` ? And how does your Attack look like exactly? How do you wait until the Attack is "finished"?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create an Enumerator

```
           if(canMove && Vector2 != 0)
             {
               canMove = false;
              rb.velocity = new Vector2(pos*walkspeed, 0);
              canAttack =false;
              StartCoroutine(AttackDelay());
             }

             IEnumerator AttackDelay(){
               yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsYouWantToStopAttacking);
               canMove = true;
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general I would rather use an `enum` state instead of multiple exclusive `bool` fields:

```
private enum State
{
    Idle,
    Moving,
    Attacking
}

[SerializeField] private State _state = State.Idle;

void Update()
{
    float x;

    switch(_state)
    {
        case State.Idle:
           // While you are Idle you can do both
           // either start moving or attacking

           x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

           rb.velocity = new Vector2(x * walkspeed, 0);

           if(!Mathf.Approximately(x, 0f))
           {
               _state = State.Moving;
           }
           else
           {
               if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
               {
                   _state = State.Attacking;
                   Attack();
               }
           }
           break;

        case State.Moving:
           // while already moving you can only either continue moving or stop
           // and go back to idle

           x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

           rb.velocity = new Vector2(x * walkspeed, 0);

           if(Mathf.Approximately(x, 0f))
           {
               _state = State.Idle;
           }
           break;

        case State.Attacking:
           // While you are attacking you can only wait until attack is finished
           // and go back to idle

           rb.velocity = Vector2. zero;

           // TODO: Since I don't know what Attack() does exactly
           // TODO: Somehow wait Until Attack is finished and then set back
           //_state = State.Idle;
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I try this if it's working I update if it's working